# The JSON value could not be converted to Univi.Shared.Report (Blazor)

Tags: json, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a page where i want to show the selected details of a specific report.
The user clicks on a link to open the specified report with id.
When i try to open the page, the above error accured.
I use routing to send the id to the page.
When i am testing my api, i will get the JSON format correctly. Even the model class seems to be okay. I have tested this with a online Json to C# converter.

This is the error which i get on the initialization of the page:

Here are the page details:

The razor page:

```
@page "/ReportDetails/{id}"
@using Univi.Client.Services;
@using Univi.Shared
@inject IReportService ReportService;


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
       
 
    </div>

</div>

@code{
    private Report CurrentReport;
    [Parameter]
    public string id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CurrentReport = await ReportService.GetSingleReportAsync(id);
    }

}
```

The service class:

`    public class ReportService : IReportService
{
private readonly HttpClient _http;

```
    public ReportService(HttpClient http)
    {
        _http = http;
    }

    public async Task<Report> GetSingleReportAsync(string id)
    {
        var report = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<Report>($"api/report/{id}");
        return report;
    }

    public async Task<List<Report>> GetReportsAsync()
    {
        var report = await  _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Report>>($"api/report");
        return report;
    }
}
```

}`

The Report Model class

`namespace Univi.Shared
{
public class Report
{

```
    //General information
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateAdded { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateClosed { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastEditOn { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public bool attetionRequired { get; set; }
    public string addedByUser { get; set; }
    public string lastEditById { get; set; }
    public string closedByUserId { get; set; }
    public string kindOfReportId { get; set; }
    public string buildingId { get; set; }

}
```

}`

Maby it is someting silly, but i cannot find the problem here. I hope someone could find what is wrong.

- Tested the API on the url to check if the API is working:
  https://localhost:44373/api/report/11

The output:

`[ { "id": "11", "dateAdded": "1989-07-15T00:00:00", "description": "Test", "dateClosed": "2002-07-15T00:00:00", "lastEditOn": "2003-02-02T00:00:00", "isActive": true, "attetionRequired": false, "addedByUser": "1", "lastEditById": "1", "closedByUserId": "1", "kindOfReportId": "2", "buildingId": "1" } ]`

- Comared above JSON/ model file with https://json2csharp.com/.

Comment: When you are specifying an id, you still get a list and not directly the object. So you should have: `var report = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Report>>($"api/report/{id}");`.